# CollapsingToolbarLayout with two views, make one scroll but not the other

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an activity with a toolbar and a recyclerview. On top of the recyclerview I have a panel that I want to be scrollable (to move along with the scroll of the recyclerview).

I want this panel to scroll behind the toolbar, so when the scrolling happens, the toolbar stays in place and the panel slides behind it.

Kind of what they do here:

https://i.imgur.com/fQA6bPH.gif

But I cant find the right combination of options with CollapsingToolbarLayout to achieve this effect:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.profile.ProfileActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark">


                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/detail_collapsing"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                        app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5">


        ...


           </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    (...)
    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

To simplify, I've changed the structure to this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/detail_collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/bar"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It does exactly the same when we add an `ImageView` inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` like this with `parallax` flag of `app:layout_collapseMode`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="pin" />

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/cheese_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" //Here is the solution
                android:minHeight="100dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

So you may want to add :

```
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

To your view (`LinearLayout`) or anything inside.

**Read:** https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout#creating-parallax-animations

Comment: This does not keep the toolbar at the top like in the gif i posted

Comment: Oh, missed that one. Updated the answer. Simply, use pin flag.

Comment: also does not work, the other answer also suggested that

Comment: That doesn’t seem to be the issue. Try removing `android:gravity` from `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by moving Toolbar outside of AppBarLayout. Then in code setup Toolbar as SupportActionBar.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.profile.ProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Dark">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/detail_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                ...

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        (...)
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

***You need to change this to get desired effect:***

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/bar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/topbar_gradient"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Your change was in `CollapsingToolbar`, by using these three attributes `"scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|exitUntilCollapsed"` together will change that effect.

---

### **Description :**

`app:layout_collapseMode=""` is attribute used to collapse/pin child views of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

There are three attributes to this :

`none` : No effects at all.

`pin` : Pin that view at CollapsingToolbar when scrolled.

`parallax` : Hide view parallel with CollapsingToolbar hiding.

so if you're having `Toolbar` pinned to `CollapsingToolbarLayout` then add this property `pin` *(which will pin it to Collapsing toolbar when scrolled)* and `parallax` will animate it until *collapsed*.

---

### Let's see

> How does scrolling actually works using these 4 attributes in
>   **`app:layout_scrollFlags=""`**
>
> **`scroll`** : *The view will be scroll in direct relation to scroll
>   events.(Necessary, otherwise any other attribute won't work)*
>
> **`enterAlways`** : *When entering (scrolling on screen) the view will
>   scroll on any downwards scroll event, regardless of whether the
>   scrolling view is also scrolling.*
>
> **`enterAlwaysCollapsed`** : *An additional flag for 'enterAlways' which
>   modifies the returning view to only initially scroll back to it's
>   collapsed height.*
>
> **`exitUntilCollapsed`** : *When exiting (scrolling off screen) the view
>   will be scrolled until it is 'collapsed'.*
>
> **`snap`** : *Upon a scroll ending, if the view is only partially visible
>   then it will be snapped and scrolled to it's closest edge.*
>
> [More details from here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams#constants_2) & [demo here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)

---

> Findout more from here : [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams)

Comment: This does not work, toolbar moves along with the scroll

Comment: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"` change this to `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, it's not working because of this `scrollFlags`. @GabrielSanmartin

Comment: I updated my question with the code you proposed, simplifying everything a bit, and it still does not work.